# Perfect 1 error correcting codes non-isomorphic to Hamming codes?

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory

In [this question](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/perfect_2_error_correcting_codes_over_arbitrary_finite_alphabets) about perfect 2 error correcting codes on the Open Problem Garden, it is stated that:

> Recent research activity has discovered a large number of previously unknown perfect 1-error correcting codes which are not isomorphic to the Hamming codes.

In terms of context, the following is well known for $t-$error correcting codes over finite alphabets:

No perfect $t-$error correcting codes other than the repetition codes (any $t\geq 1,$ any alphabet, odd length), the Hamming codes (binary alphabet, $t=1$) and the two Golay codes (binary with length $n=23$ and $t=3$ and ternary with length $n=11,$ and $t=2$) exist in the Hamming metric when the alphabet size $q$ is a prime power.

**Question:** *Does anyone here know what these (recently found circa 2010) codes are?*

The below is the stated open question for $t=2,$ but to be a conjecture it must actually say there are or there aren't such codes:

> Conjecture:   Does there exist a nontrivial perfect 2-error-correcting code over any finite alphabet, other than the ternary Golay code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back in 1986, Phelps provides many examples which is clear from the title of his paper [Every finite group is the automorphism group of some perfect code](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/009731658690021X?via%3Dihub), J. Combin. Theory Ser. A43(1986), no.1, 45–51.

Comment: I am specifically interested in the alphabet sizes $q,$ e.g., $q=6,$ where it is open whether a perfect code exists. It is not clear to me from the paper if it applies to nonbinary codes and how.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of information in the recent book:
"Perfect Codes and Related Structures," by T. Etzion.
The notes to Chapter 5 contain a long list of references.
In particular, if you're interested in codes over general alphabets, the best (to my knowledge) necessary condition appears in:
O. Heden and C. Roos, "[The non-existence of some perfect codes over non-prime
power alphabets](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.disc.2011.03.024)," Discrete Mathematics, vol. 311, no. 14, pp. 1344-1348, 2011.